# MongoDB Finding Distinct values of the Nth element of an array using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Suppose I have a collection with the following documents:

```
{ id: 1, values: [ 1, 6, 3, 9 ] }
{ id: 2, values: [ 2, 1, 2, 4 ] }
{ id: 3, values: [ 3, 2, 3, 2 ] }
{ id: 4, values: [ 4, 4, 3, 6 ] }
{ id: 5, values: [ 5, 8, 2, 9 ] }
```

I want to execute "Select distinct in values[2]" over the collection.
The result would be:

```
[ 3, 2 ]
```

How can I do this using the C# driver?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?  What research have you done on how to perform each of these operations?  What problems are you having with your existing implementations, or with the results of your research?

Comment: I'm designing a data model for complex data, so I want to know if this operations are even possible to perform efficiently on mongodb. If not, I'll change either the model or the db.

Answer (score 0):

Edit according to the comment:

Get distinct values from column 2:

```
collection.AsQueryable<Model>().Select(x => x.Values[2]).Distinct();
```

Get distinct values from row 2:

```
collection.AsQueryable<Model>().Skip(2).Take(1).Select(x => x.Values).Distinct();
```

Comment: The way I understand the OP, he wants a distinct set of values of the *column* with the index 2, not the row, so to speak. Unfortunately, the example is ambiguous, because both the 3rd row and column have the same set of distinct values...

Comment: On the first example, if I require a Where before the Select projection, Is it executed on MongoDB or the Where will retrieve all its results to then perform the Distinct locally?